# Error: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to create a new library that will be shared across other modules in the projects. Unfortunately, though when I try to create one, I get the mentioned error before the gradle even builds:

```
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

Here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I've tried reading several similar threads where people recommends to remove java plugin, but I don't see any in my new library. However I do see a java plugin in my root gradle:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  println "applying java plugin to $project"
  apply plugin: 'java-library'

  sourceSets {
    main {
      java {
        srcDirs = ["src"]
      }
      resources {
        srcDirs = ["src/resources"]
      }
    }
  }

  sourceCompatibility = 1.7
  targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

What do you think might be the issue?

Comment: You probably have other Gradle files in your project (specifically at the root of the project); do any of those mention the Java plugin?

Comment: @stkent I do, it's `apply plugin: 'java-library'` but I can't change that, how do I resolve this in the current library?

Comment: Where exactly is `apply plugin: 'java-library'`? In your root build.gradle file, or a sibling build.gradle file? Please add code that shows how it's invoked too. Thanks!

Comment: @stkent yes, it's in the root gradle. Just update my OP for you to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  println "applying java plugin to $project"
  apply plugin: 'java-library'

  //...
}
```

declares that the Java library plugin should be applied to every Gradle project in your codebase. Note that the `java` plugins (application, library) are generally incompatible with the `android` plugins (application, library). You can think of the latter as being heavily modified versions of the former.

This incompatibility causes the error you see.

The best resolution depends on the purposes of your codebase as a whole and the Gradle projects within it. The least invasive options are likely:

1. Remove `apply plugin: 'java-library'` and related configuration from the `allprojects` configuration and instead manually apply the plugin in each Gradle project that needs it;
2. Add a special case in your `allprojects` configuration so that the `java-library` plugin is applied to all projects *except* the new one.

To expand on the second case, you could do something like:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  if (getPath() != "absolute/path/to/new/project") {
    println "applying java plugin to $project"
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    // ...
  }
}
```

I used `getPath` here since `getName` is not guaranteed to be unique in general, but if it is in your particular case then that would be a friendlier conditional to write and read.

Comment: You're right! I just had to get rid of the java plugin in the new library. I worked my way around it in another way that I'll share below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @stkent mentions, we just have to get rid of either the java plugin, or exclude the library from configuration of allprojects in the root gradle. How I worked my way around it was by adding the following to the root gradle where the java plugin was applied:

```
configure(allprojects - project(':NewLibraryName')) {
    println "applying java plugin to $project"
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    //...
}
```

Comment: Nice, very neat solution!